# Get content of selected rows from JTable as ArrayList of Objects

Tags: java, arrays, swing, arraylist, jtable

I want to gather the contents of a selected row into an array of the type Object. To gather the contents from all selected rows, these arrays should then be added to an arraylist that is later returned.

**Simplyfied approach:**

```
Content of row --> Object[i] = content of column 1...2...3...i
ArrayList<Object[]> add <-- Object[]
```

**The ArrayList should then be something like this:**

```
list {

[(content of row(0), col(0)), content of row(0), col(1)), content of row(0), col(1))],

[(content of row(1), col(0)), content of row(1), col(1)), content of row(1), col(1))]


[(content of row(2), col(0)), content of row(2), col(1)), content of row(2), col(1))]

}
```

In the following you will find the code I have so far but this is not working right, I am getting null pointer exceptions.

```
public static ArrayList<Object[]> getSelectedTaskAsList() {
    ArrayList<Object[]> tasks = new ArrayList<Object[]>();

    if (table.getSelectedRowCount() > 0) { // check if there are selected rows
        int[] selectedRows = table.getSelectedRows();
        Object[] taskAsArray = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < selectedRows.length; i++) { // print all selected tasks
            for (int j = 0; j < table.getColumnCount(); j++) {
                taskAsArray[j] = (table.getValueAt(table.convertRowIndexToModel(selectedRows[i]),table.convertColumnIndexToModel(j)));
            }
            tasks.add(taskAsArray);
        }
    }
    return tasks;
}
```

First of all I would like to know if my approach is "good" or if it is too difficult or if there is an alternative approach. The null pointer exception occurs upon adding the first value from the table to the `taskAsArray[]` array.

Comment: If you  need additional information, please let me know, I wanted to hold this as simple as possible.

Comment: I don't know if Simplyfied approach is good idea, you know very well what do you do for ...., just avoiding simplyfied answres to quite empty question

Comment: NPE is simplyfied output from wrong design or code

Comment: @mKorbel You might be right, but I was unsure if my question was clear enough because this is just some excerpt code from a bigger project so I wanted to explain my "demands" as easy to understand as possible.

Comment: but this would include the case if there are no rows selected, which will lead to a crash. I just want this to run if there is **at least one** row selected.

Answer (score 1):

You should always indicate the location where you get exceptions. But for a start you should change this

```
    Object[] taskAsArray = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < selectedRows.length; i++) { // print all selected tasks
        for (int j = 0; j < table.getColumnCount(); j++) {
            taskAsArray[j] = (table.getValueAt(table.convertRowIndexToModel(selectedRows[i]),table.convertColumnIndexToModel(j)));
        }
        tasks.add(taskAsArray);
    }
```

into

```
    Object[] taskAsArray = new Object[table.getColumnCount()];
    for (int i = 0; i < selectedRows.length; i++) { // print all selected tasks
        for (int j = 0; j < table.getColumnCount(); j++) {
            taskAsArray[j] = (table.getValueAt(table.convertRowIndexToModel(selectedRows[i]),table.convertColumnIndexToModel(j)));
        }
        tasks.add(taskAsArray);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, I will add this in future questions.

Answer (score 1):

Change you code to

```
    Object[] taskAsArray = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < selectedRows.length; i++) { // print all selected tasks
        taskAsArray=new Object[table.getColumnCount()]; //<--- the added array init
        for (int j = 0; j < table.getColumnCount(); j++) {
            taskAsArray[j] = (table.getValueAt(table.convertRowIndexToModel(selectedRows[i]),table.convertColumnIndexToModel(j)));
        }
        tasks.add(taskAsArray);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

taskArray isn't declared properly. Also, you should have an Object array for each selected row if I understand your description correctly.

Change the declaration to:

```
Object[] taskArray = new Object[table.getColumnCount()];
```

and move it inside the first for-loop.